# getting the System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Int32] error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await

i am trying to convert my code to a sync  but when i run it 
i get in one of my vars the value "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Int32]" instead of the expected ans

i have read most of the same questions asked in this topic but none of them helped me solved the problem 
i tried to use properly the await but its isn't helped

```
public async Task<int> userloginAsync(string name,string pass)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"/////:P//////"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UserLoginPro"))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(id) FROM user_table where name =@name and password =@password; ";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pass);
                 await   con.OpenAsync();
                    var ans1 = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
                    var ans = ans1.ToString();
                    con.Close();
                    int res = Convert.ToInt32(ans);
                    con.Close();
                    return res;
                }

            }

        }
```

its should query the mssql if there is an match to inputs(username and password)
and if there is return 1
if not 0 
(in the DB there is unique usernames so it can be only one )

Comment: However you didn't mention which line or var it's getting this error I think Its most probably on `var ans = ans1.ToString();`  if yes then use `await` before your `ToString();` conversion such as `var ans = ans1.ToString();`

Comment: its the var named 'ans1'

Comment: when i try to add await it says 'string' does not contain a definition for 'getAwaiter' and not accessible methos...(i tried both of those.   1.await var ans = ans1.ToString(); and also.       var ans = await ans1.ToString(); ) and also

Comment: `string` is not an awaitable type. What were you expecting to achieve by awaiting `ToString()`?

Comment: i do that after i saw in one of the other answers asked that it might solve the issue that i mentioned

originally my code was like this
```
                 await con.OpenAsync();
                    var ans1 = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
                    var ans = ans1.ToString();
                    con.Close();
```
and this lead to the ans variable return 
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Int32]